# one of the many VS one of many

Tags: prepositions, articles

> But apparently she was just **one of the many**.
>
> But apparently she was just **one of many**.

Are there any differences between these two expressions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The one" vs "one"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120660/the-one-vs-one)

Comment: Ther linked Q&A is simialr, but not the same issue, and this should not be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*She was one of many* can stand on its own, meaning that there were many other people in a similar situation.

*She was one of the many* normally requires a continuation to state what that situation was, for example "She was one of the many who were finding life difficult at that time".